# python-roslib : Depends: catkin but it is not going to be installed

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i run the command:

```
roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch
```

I get the following message:

```
Command 'roslaunch' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install python-roslaunch
```

So I try this command, giving me the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-roslaunch : Depends: python-roslib but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I try to install python-roslib, using the command:

```
sudo apt install python-roslib. This gives me the following error: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-roslib : Depends: catkin but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anybody now how I can fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390520/python-roslib-:-depends:-catkin-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed/) by [Alex2008](https://answers.ros.org/users/89281/alex2008/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to be running into problems trying to mix [wiki/UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages) and regular ROS packages.

Note how all packages you mention don't have the name of the ROS version you're using in them: `python-roslaunch`, `python-roslib` and `catkin`.

In ROS Melodic, the correct package names would be: `ros-melodic-roslaunch`, `ros-melodic-roslib` and `ros-melodic-catkin`.

You cannot mix upstream packages with packages from a ROS release (that's not entirely true, but if you're just starting out, I would probably heed the advice given on the wiki page and not attempt to do so).
See the linked wiki page for more information about them, and see [“upstream packages” increasingly becoming a problem](https://discourse.ros.org/t/upstream-packages-increasingly-becoming-a-problem/10902) for a recent-ish discussion.

But your initial problem was:

> When i run the command: `roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch`
>
> I get the following message: Command `roslaunch` not found, but can be installed with: `sudo apt install python-roslaunch`

did you perhaps forget to `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` (or the equivalent for your workspace) *before* trying to use `roslaunch`? If you don't `source` your ROS installation (or workspace), your shell will not be able to find `roslaunch`, which on Ubuntu causes it to suggest installing the `python-roslaunch` package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-10**:
Some related Q&As: #q353082, #q359586, #q390335 and #q356158.

**Comment by [Alex2008](https://answers.ros.org/users/89281/alex2008/) on 2021-11-10**:
Thank you for your clear answer. I wasn't aware of using upstream packages with packages from a ROS release.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-10**:
So the solution would be to *not* do that.

Have you been able to solve your initial problem?

**Comment by [Alex2008](https://answers.ros.org/users/89281/alex2008/) on 2021-11-10**:
Yes I have been able to solve the problem. Only by using source/opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash the error was fixed. Thanks a lot!